# This message does not have authentication information or fails to 550-5.7.26 pass authentication checks

Tags: gmail, sendmail, spf, dkim, dmarc

I have problem with google and I can't send email to any gmail or Gsuite emails
got report from mail server log

```
Feb 17 12:16:30 server postfix/smtp[19451]: 853E35E55A: to=<xxx@gmail.com>, 
relay=aspmx.l.google.com[209.85.144.27]:25, delay=0.38, delays=0.05/0/0.15/0.17, 
dsn=5.7.26, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[209.85.144.27] said: 550-5.7.26 This 
message does not have authentication information or fails to 550-5.7.26 pass 
authentication checks. To best protect our users from spam, the 550-5.7.26 message has 
been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.26  
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550 5.7.26 
information. w19si7586061qkp.34 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

and I'm not blacklisted in any spam website ( I do check in most of website which provide blocklist checker)

also I didn't have any problem in SPF or DKIM or DMARC

here is SPF checker
https://prnt.sc/26xomwz

here is DKIM checker
https://prnt.sc/26xoodg

here is DMARC checker
https://prnt.sc/26xopgo

here is DMARC report from google

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<feedback>
  <report_metadata>
    <org_name>google.com</org_name>
    <email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>
    <extra_contact_info>https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580</extra_contact_info>
    <report_id>10254909114662490508</report_id>
    <date_range>
      <begin>1644969600</begin>
      <end>1645055999</end>
    </date_range>
  </report_metadata>
  <policy_published>
    <domain>cbs-canon.com</domain>
    <adkim>r</adkim>
    <aspf>r</aspf>
    <p>quarantine</p>
    <sp>quarantine</sp>
    <pct>100</pct>
  </policy_published>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>5.161.45.186</source_ip>
      <count>187</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>quarantine</disposition>
        <dkim>fail</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>server.cbs-canon.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>server.cbs-canon.com</domain>
        <result>fail</result>
        <selector>default</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>server.cbs-canon.com</domain>
        <result>none</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>5.161.45.186</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>cbs-canon.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>cbs-canon.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>default</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>cbs-canon.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
</feedback>
```

how can I know where is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is odd. The sending source IP is definitely in your SPF, and the DMARC record includes `aspf=r`, so the header from address in a child domain is valid and matches. I'd also note that your DMARC has `p=quarantine`, but gmail is acting like it's `reject`. This is gmail though, so you can't expect it to behave well.

I expect that the problem is that you don't have an SPF record set for `server.cbs-canon.com`, so make sure that exists and allows the same sources as `cbs-canon.com`. It looks like you're not doing DKIM signatures either, meaning that both SPF and DKIM are failing, resulting in a DMARC failure. Try adding that DNS record, or redirecting/including `server.` to your root domain.

Comment: perfect, there was miss configuratation in DKIM signatures.. I have fixed them and also I have disable bounce notification for root@hostname, because it was caching the bounce message

Comment: but I have another problem, emails got to the SPAM folder. I found that CSF sending emails from root@hostname (which hostname in my current hostname), and it's marked as spam.. as CSF is sending many messages, all of them are sent to SPAM .. even if I marked them as non-spam.. still, any email from CSF and other normal email send to spam.. Gmail said `Why is this message in spam? It is similar to messages that were identified as spam in the past.`

Comment: Is CSF your firewall software? If it is sending as a non-routable, possibly single-label domain, then it will be downgraded in reputation by many Mailbox Service Providers. Because multitude of checks cant be performed or fail. Try and configure a proper FROM address/domain instead.

Comment: Unfortunately with gmail it’s probably more accurately “messages that we misidentified as spam before”. Good point by @Reinto though – make sure you’re using a full domain, not just a bare hostname in your from address.

Answer (score 1):

Adding more info for @Synchro 's answer.

It is the fact that the `Return-Path` address is using the `server.cbs-canon.com` domain and there is no SPF record in that zone. You only need an SPF record for the domain used in your `Return-Path` address. For your server's emails that would be `server.cbs-canon.com`. For Google that would probably be just `cbs-canon.com`.

The same goes for DKIM. The receiving server is checking for the selector named `default` in the domain `server.cbs-canon.com` (so doing a query for TXT record `default._domainkey.server.cbs-canon.com`), which does not exist.

DMARC will then check if either the SPF (`Return-Path`) or DKIM (`d=`) domain aligns with the `Header.From` domain (or sharing the oranizational domain in case of relaxed mode).

Probably the easiest fix for you right now is to copy the SPF TXT record and DKIM selector record to the `server.cbs-canon.com` domain.

Comment: thanks for your notes, its also applied and the email now is sent.. but as my last reply for @Synhro its send to SPAM folder